# Rails, how to know if the request is coming from localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, localhost

I have to determine if the request is coming from localhost.

I am trying:

For request `http://localhost:3000`

```
# MyController
request.local?     # -> 0
request.host       # -> localhost
request.ip         # -> ::1
request.remote_ip  # -> ::1
```

For request `http://127.0.0.1:3000`

```
# MyController
request.local?     # -> 0
request.host       # -> 127.0.0.1
request.ip         # -> 127.0.0.1
request.remote_ip  # -> 127.0.0.1
```

I would like to know if there is an standard way to do it. This looks like the solution: [ApplicationController.local_request?](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/ApplicationController/local_request%3F) but is *protected* and is not working properly because `request.local?` is returning `0` for local requests.

I also can not trust in the `request.host` because it can be faked by `/etc/hosts` tricks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`request.local?` works, it returns `0` and is therefore `true` in Ruby, since everything in Ruby is `true` except `false` and `nil`.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d2dde6cbfc11bf39be30d22e2ee7c41c119e0d51/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L377) it's done with a regex, and so `0` is the expected and correct result

```
def local?
  LOCALHOST =~ remote_addr && LOCALHOST =~ remote_ip
end
```

---

**Update Rails 6.1 (probably)**

The current master branch of Rails now does this with the `match?` method and therefore will return `true` or `false`

[Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L415)

```
def local?
  LOCALHOST.match?(remote_addr) && LOCALHOST.match?(remote_ip)
end
```